# Create pdf and merge with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, merge, pdfbox

This is what I want to do:

1. Make 2 different pdf files using pdfbox
2. Merge these two files together using pdfmerger

I know how to do this if I'm saving #1 to the server side local hard drive and load the files for the #2. But what I want to do is using "directly from the memory".  I've searched all the methods from this pdfboxes but still couldn't find it.

This is my code getting from the local file

Thank you.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility;

/**
* This is an example that creates a simple document
* with a ttf-font.
*
* @author <a href="mailto:m.g.n@gmx.de">Michael Niedermair</a>
* @version $Revision: 1.2 $
*/
public class Test2
{

    /**
    * create the second sample document from the PDF file format specification.
    *
    * @param file     The file to write the PDF to.
    * @param message    The message to write in the file.
    * @param fontfile  The ttf-font file.
    *
    * @throws IOException If there is an error writing the data.
    * @throws COSVisitorException If there is an error writing the PDF.
    */
    public void doIt(final String file, final String message) throws IOException, COSVisitorException
    {

        // the document
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = new PDDocument();

            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;


            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
            contentStream.drawString(message);
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();

            doc.save(file);

            System.out.println(file + " created!");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                doc.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will create a hello world PDF document
     * with a ttf-font.
     * <br />
     * see usage() for commandline
     *
     * @param args Command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Test2 app = new Test2();
        Test2 app2 = new Test2();
        try {
            app.doIt("C:/here.pdf", "hello");
            app2.doIt("C:/here2.pdf", "helloagain");
            PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
            merger.addSource("C:/here.pdf");
            merger.addSource("C:/here2.pdf");
            OutputStream bout2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/hereisthefinal.pdf"));

            merger.setDestinationStream(bout2);
            merger.mergeDocuments();

        } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to use the [`PdfMergeUtility.addSource(InputStream)`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFMergerUtility.html) method to add source from an inputstream and not from a physical file.

With a quick glance at the API, what you could do is use the [`PDDocument.save(OutputStream)`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream%29) method to write the file into a byte array in memory, something like this should work.

```
static byte[] doIt(String message) {
   PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
   // add the message
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   doc.save(baos);
   return baos.toByteArray();
}

void main(String args[]) {
   byte[] pdf1 = doIt("hello");
   byte[] pdf2 = doIt("world");
   PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
   merger.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf1));
   merger.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf2));
   // do the rest with the merger
}
```

Comment: Thank you very muck :) This Input OutputStream converting stuff really makes me tired :(. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I use this to merge some documents (InputStreams) and write the merged document in a HttpServletResponse.

```
  PDFMergerUtility mergedDoc = new PDFMergerUtility();
  ByteArrayOutputStream colDocOutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  for (int i = 0; i < documentCount; i++)
  {
    ByteArrayOutputStream tempZipOutstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
...
    mergedDoc.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(tempZipOutstream.toByteArray()));
  }

  mergedDoc.setDestinationStream(colDocOutputstream);
  mergedDoc.mergeDocuments();

  response.setContentLength(colDocOutputstream.size());
  response.setContentType("application/pdf");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=mergedDocument.pdf");
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
  response.addDateHeader("Expires", 0);
  response.getOutputStream().write(colDocOutputstream.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this way also:-**
1) Create List of InputStream
2) Instantiate PDFMergerUtility class
3) Set Destination Output Stream
4) Add all InputStreams to PDFMerger as Source files which needs to be merged.
5) Merge the documents by calling "`PDFmerger.mergeDocuments();`"

```
   List<InputStream> locations=new ArrayList<InputStream>();
        locations.add(new FileInputStream("E:/Filenet Project Support/MergePDFs_Sample_Code/Attorney_new_form.pdf"));
        locations.add(new FileInputStream("E:/Filenet Project Support/MergePDFs_Sample_Code/JH.pdf"));
        locations.add(new FileInputStream("E:/Filenet Project Support/MergePDFs_Sample_Code/Interpreter_new_form.pdf"));
        //Instantiating PDFMergerUtility class
        PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
        //Setting Destination Output Stream
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("E:/Filenet Project Support/MergePDFs_Sample_Code/merged.pdf");
        //Adding all InputStreams to PDFMerger as Source files which needs to be merged.
        PDFmerger.addSources(locations);
        //Setting Destination Output Stream
        PDFmerger.setDestinationStream(out);
        //Merging the two documents
        PDFmerger.mergeDocuments();
        System.out.println("Documents merged");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using REST and PDFBOX**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMergePdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getMergePdf(@RequestParam(value = "filePath", required = true) String filePath,
            @RequestParam(value = "newFileName", required = true) String newFileName) throws IOException {

            // Step 1: Loading an Existing PDF Document
        File file = new File(filePath);
        File[] listFile = file.listFiles();

        // Step 2: Instantiating the PDFMergerUtility class
        PDFMergerUtility mergePdf = new PDFMergerUtility();

        // Step 3: Setting the source files
        for (File pdfName : listFile) {
            mergePdf.addSource(pdfName);
        }

        // Step 4: Setting the destination file
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfDocOutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mergePdf.setDestinationFileName(newFileName + ".pdf");
        mergePdf.setDestinationStream(pdfDocOutputstream);
        mergePdf.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

        // Step 5: write in Response
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);

        // Here you have to set the actual filename of your pdf
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(mergePdf.getDestinationFileName(), mergePdf.getDestinationFileName());
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(pdfDocOutputstream.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;


    }
```

Comment: Why do you read the pdfs into byte arrays and add these arrays as sources? There is an `addSource` that accepts a `File` argument. Most likely using that overload would mean a smaller memory footprint.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion .....,update code as per your comment