# PDFBox - Create java.io.InputStream from String

Tags: java, inputstream, pdfbox

I am integrating my RESTful service to support download of documents etc. For that I am exploring PDFBox library which has capability to work with PDF docs (fantastic) and it works OK if I have to create and save documents.

My example code looks like following;

```
    PDDocument doc = null;
PDPage page = null;
try{
    doc = new PDDocument();
    page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page);
    content.beginText();
    content.drawString("Some Content Received At Runtime");
    content.endText();
    content.close();
    doc.save("SomeName.pdf");
    doc.close();

    // Now load and return the stream
    return PDDocument.load("SomeName.pdf").getDocument().createCOSStream().getFilteredStream();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do nothing for now
}
```

If you see in above example I have an option to convert document into InputStream but to achieve this I first have to **Save the document and then reload!** This is not desirable because this will clutter the server I am running on with junk.

What I really want is to achieve this without saving the document! Is it possible? Should I be looking at some other library like iText? If you know an example for the same please share.

Comment: What happens when you call `doc.createCOSStream()` directly instead of saving it first?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can "save" the document into memory and read it back from there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808251/14955

Comment: As proposed by @Thilo use the `doc.save` overload which accepts an `OutputStream` with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, get the `byte[]` from it and wrap that in a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for...will try and update this thread... first method didn't work...also seems bit untidy....